# Rails + Carrierwave: How to change default file naming of image versions (thumb, small, etc)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading my project from Rails 2 with attachment_fu to Rails 3 with carrierwave. I have an existing database and file directory with images that were uploaded using attachment_fu. Problem is that in attachment_fu, images were uploaded with the image version (thumb, small, medium, etc) appended to the back of the filename (`my_image_small.jpg`) while in carrierwave, the default is the other way around (`small_my_image.jpg`). Where in carrierwave would I change this?

here's my FileUploader:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  #include UploaderFu
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:

  SMALL_WIDTH = 101 
    MEDIUM_WIDTH = 223
    LARGE_WIDTH = 345

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    #{}"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    "#{Rails.root}/public/file_uploads/#{("%08d" % model.id).scan(/..../).join('/')}"
    #{}"#{Rails.root}/public/file_uploads/"
  end

  version :small do
    process :resize_to_fit => [SMALL_WIDTH, 10000]
  end

  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_fit => [MEDIUM_WIDTH, 10000]
  end

  version :large do
    process :resize_to_fit => [LARGE_WIDTH, 10000]
  end




  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :scale => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Comment: I am using Carrierwave gem and when i download the file, if that file name contains space then it's converted into underscores. So how to remove that underscore from the filename while downloading it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To override the filename convention for a specific version, you can define a `full_filename` method in the version block:

```
version :small do
  def full_filename(for_file)
    [super(for_file), version_name].compact.join('_')
  end

  process :resize_to_fit => [SMALL_WIDTH, 10000]
end
```

This method is simply a rewrite of the existing `full_filename` method in the CarrierWave source code (see `versions.rb`).

You'll need to override this on every version, however. Instead, you might want to change CarrierWave's default behavior by patching the `Versions` module. You can add this an an initializer:

```
module CarrierWave
  module Uploader
    module Versions
      def full_filename(for_file)
        [super(for_file), version_name].compact.join('_')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Update:**

To correct the issue with the file extension, you can use Rake's `pathmap` function to parse the filename:

```
require 'rake'
def full_filename(for_file)
  filename  = for_file.pathmap("%n")
  extension = for_file.pathmap("%x")
  [filename, version_name].compact.join('_') + extension
end
```

Comment: hey Zach I actually didn't see your answer and tried that out, but the issue with switching version_name and super(for_file) like that is that the filename becomes `my_image.jpg_small` look at my answer, kinda hacky but I had to use regex to split the filename into everything before .jpg and after .jpg and stick the version_name in between

Comment: Hmm, didn't think of that (I wrote this without testing it - sorry). I've updated by answer with another option that wouldn't require you to use regex.

Comment: it worked great thanks! I think that'll be way more reliable than my regex.

Comment: I am using Carrierwave gem and when i download the file, if that file name contains space then it's converted into underscores. So how to remove that underscore from the filename while downloading it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone wants to know how I figured it out, I looked into the gem code and found out the filename was being set by `def full_filename`, so in my FileUploader I rewrote the method so that it would overwrite the behavior.

```
def full_filename (for_file = model.filename.file)      
  "#{for_file[/(.+)\./][$1]}_#{version_name}.#{for_file[/\.(.+)/][$1]}"
end
```

Comment: I am using Carrierwave gem and when i download the file, if that file name contains space then it's converted into underscores. So how to remove that underscore from the filename while downloading it ?